# log4j-slf4j-impl cannot be present with log4j-to-slf4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, log4j

I have a POC springboot scheduled task program. When I try to run one of my `producer` methods, I get the error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggingException: log4j-slf4j-impl cannot be present with log4j-to-slf4j
```

I understand that `log4j-to-slf4j` is required for the scheduler to work for `spring-bott-starter-web` dependency so I updated my `build.gradle` to:

```java
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.6.6'
    testImplementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:4.2.0'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    implementation group: 'org.apache.pulsar', name: 'pulsar-client', version: '2.9.2'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.avro', name: 'avro', version: '1.10.2'
   //implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.17.1'

    implementation group: 'com.climate', name: 'event-platform-java-client', version: '0.0.41'
    implementation group: 'com.climate', name: 'event-platform-java-admin-client', version: '0.0.1'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
}
```

However, the error still persists.

#### Things I've tried

##### Blowing my cache

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository
```

However, I can still see the dependencies are still present.

[image: Intellij External Library list]

##### Invalidate Caches in Intellij

File > Invalidate Caches
I've applied the optional settings:

- Clear file system cache and Local History
- Clear downloaded shared indexes

I can still see the Dependencies listed in the external Library section in my Project window.

###### Running `dependencyInsight`

```
➜ ./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency log4j-slf4j-impl

> Task :dependencyInsight
No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration ':compileClasspath'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Seems to never think the dependency is listed, but I am still getting the error and I can see it in the External Libraries

###### `./gradlew cleanBuildCache`

```
➜ ./gradlew cleanBuildCache

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'cleanBuildCache' not found in root project 'event-platform-canary-tests'.
```

##### clear .gradle/cache

```
➜ rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches 
➜ ./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies
```

Answer (score -1):

I think refactoring my `build.gradle` worked better:

```java
dependencies {
    implementation (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.6.6') {
        exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
    }
    testImplementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:4.2.0'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    ...
    //implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.17.1'
    ...
}
```